# SimplecartJs - Select size doesn't works with ie 8

Tags: select, internet-explorer-8, simplecart

I am facing compatibility trouble with Internet Explorer 8 using SimplecartJS:

I have a select to choice size: (shop.php)

```
<select class="item_Size">
    <option value="15 x 10 cm">15 x 10 cm - 2€</option>
    <option value="15 x 21 cm">15 x 21 cm - 3€</option>
    <option value="21 x 29,7 cm">21 x 29,7 cm - 5€</option>
    <option value="21 x 29,7 cm encadré">21 x 29,7 cm encadré - 20€</option>
</select>
```

And a little JS Script to set price about the size: (script.js)

```
simpleCart.bind( 'beforeAdd' , function( item )
{
    if( item.get( 'size' ) == '15 x 10 cm' )
    {
        item.price( '2' );
    }
    else if( item.get( 'size' ) == '15 x 21 cm' )
    {
        item.price( '3' );
    }
    else if( item.get( 'size' ) == '21 x 29,7 cm' )
    {
        item.price( '5' );
    }
    else if( item.get( 'size' ) == '21 x 29,7 cm encadré' )
    {
        item.price( '20' );
    }
});
```

It works perfectly in Firefox, Safari, etc, but not in ie 8 (Not tested in ie 7).

I already try without simple quotes around item.price value in JS script (item.price( 20 );) but nothing change.

Does someone have an idea to help me fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok folks, i did it !
I don't know if syntax is correct and i think it could be minimize but it works in IE 8.
I hope it helps someone:

```
if ( $.browser.msie )
{
    $('.item_add').click(function()
    {
        var id_du_select_photo_ie = this.id;
        var selecteur = 'selec' + id_du_select_photo_ie;
        var selectionne = ' option:selected';
        var valeur_select_photo_ie = $('#selec' + id_du_select_photo_ie + selectionne).val();       
        simpleCart.bind("beforeAdd", function(item)
        {
            if(valeur_select_photo_ie == "15 x 10 cm")
            {
                item.price(2);
                item.set( "size" , valeur_select_photo_ie );
            }
            else if(valeur_select_photo_ie == "15 x 21 cm")
            {
                item.price(3);
                item.set( "size" , valeur_select_photo_ie );
            }
            else if(valeur_select_photo_ie == "21 x 29,7 cm")
            {
                item.price(5);
                item.set( "size" , valeur_select_photo_ie );
            }
            else if(valeur_select_photo_ie == "21 x 29,7 cm encadré")
            {
                item.price(20);
                item.set( "size" , valeur_select_photo_ie );
            }
        });
    });
}

if ( !$.browser.msie )
{
    simpleCart.bind("beforeAdd", function(item)
    {   
        if(item.get("size") == "15 x 10 cm")
        {
            item.price(2);
        }
        else if(item.get("size") == "15 x 21 cm")
        {
            item.price(3);
        }
        else if(item.get("size") == "21 x 29,7 cm")
        {
            item.price(5);
        }
        else if(item.get("size") == "21 x 29,7 cm encadré")
        {
            item.price(20);
        }
    });
}
```

;-)